# AWS Amplify - Is there an API to validate the code sent using forgotPassword and change the password after the validation?

Tags: javascript, aws-amplify, amplifyjs, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I'm using cognito user pools for user management and using the flow of forgotPassword a confirmation code is sent to the user. For UI purposes I need to validate the code that is sent when I call the API ForgotPassword without sending the new password yet. I need like a middle step between ForgotPassword and ConfirmForgotPassword.

The function below is the one sending the code:

```html
Auth.forgotPassword(username)
```

This function is resetting the password with the code sent (here I'm notified if the code is invalid)

```js
Auth.forgotPasswordSubmit(username, code, new_password)
```

Is it possible to only validate the code sent with the existing API's available?

Here a link with information:
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/manageusers/q/platform/js#forgot-password

Comment: Did you ever work this out? I am currently searching for the same answer. Is there a way to get it to verify all fields and return all errors at once, and just send an empty string for the password?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to do it. I ended up collecting in the UI the two parameters required code and the new password with a stepper component, then I called the API with all the required parameters.